# Run ejs-lint automatically on error in express

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am using ejs with express, and there is an error in my ejs code

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.' in 
.../views/pages/index.ejs while compiling ejs

If the above error is not helpful, you may want to try EJS-Lint:
https://github.com/RyanZim/EJS-Lint
```

And yep, that was a pretty unhelpful error, so I added ejs-lint to my server.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const ejs = require('ejs');
const ejsLint = require('ejs-lint');

// setup configs
dotenv.config();
const config = process.env;

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// routes
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  try {
    console.log('attempting to render');
    res.render('pages/index');
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Should get here'); // this line is never hit
  }
});

// gotta get yourself connected
app.listen(config.port, () =>
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${config.port}`)
);
```

But the try/catch isn't working and it would be great if this was somehow integrated with express render.